# java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 0

Tags: java, jmx, rhel

I have about 20 java processes that start up using

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
```

in their command line, with no explicit port number specified.

My understanding is that this means the JVM gets assigned any free port from the ephemeral port range.

This has worked without problem for many years.

Last week, I had a one-off event where some of the processes failed to start up because  of the following:

```
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 0; nested exception is:java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

The problem is not reproducible, and I have not seen this one before.

As I understand it, Port 0 is another term for any ephemeral port. As they are assigned to the JVM by the system, how can an ephemeral port  already be in use?

```
[me@server:/tmp]cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
32768   61000
```

There should be about 29000 ports available; does this error indicate that they were all in use at the time my processes requested them?

Comment: did you solve this problem ?